# Heroku, NodeJS, MongoDB, process exited status 1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am doing a nodejs course and am not able to deploy app to heroku. The App stack is nodejs, express, mongodb. 
**The Problem**
I am getting a `Process exited with status 1` from heroku after pushing my code. 
Here is my app configuration for connecting to database.

```
module.exports=function(){
  let db = config.get('db');
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    db = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
  }
mongoose.connect(db)
  .then(() => winston.info(`Connected to ${db}...`));
}
```

my config vars in heroku

```
MONGODB_URI mongodb+srv://vidlyuser:password@cluster0-b8ezs.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
NODE_ENV production
NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL verbose
```

My greatest challenge is that heroku error logs are not as helpful.

```
State changed from starting to crashed
Process exited with status 1
```

heroku logs --tail

```
2020-03-23T07:10:56.519157+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the vidly@1.0.0 start script.
2020-03-23T07:10:56.519289+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-03-23T07:10:56.519715+00:00 app[web.1]: npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
2020-03-23T07:10:56.533850+00:00 app[web.1]: npm timing npm Completed in 1161ms
2020-03-23T07:10:56.534215+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-23T07:10:56.534554+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-03-23T07:10:56.534856+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-03-23T07_10_56_520Z-debug.log
2020-03-23T07:10:56.609864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-23T07:10:56.592043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Followed [Heroku Node.js app "Process exited with status 1" and error h10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713758/heroku-node-js-app-process-exited-with-status-1-and-error-h10). But no change.

this [npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle) didnt help either

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the original env file and redo it

```
heroku config:set MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://vidlyuser:password@cluster0-b8ezs.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose
```

Comment: I think this is  Mosh Hamedani course and if you follow his tutorial nicely,there won't be any problem

Comment: it is the one. but it was made 2 yrs ago. so issues do arise. because i have followed it to the end

Answer (score 0):

In my effort to fix this issue i learnt that i miss understood the error. i learnt The error `npm ERR! Failed at the vidly@1.0.0 start script.` usually points to an underlying error. making use of exception logging in my code i was able to discover the actual error and this had to do with a particular npm package.

The solution is `npm ERR! Failed at the vidly@1.0.0 start script.` usually points to another error.