# starting a Discord Bot in heroku causes errors that i dont have when starting it from cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

When I deploy the bot in **Heroku**, the build is successful, but then the bot crashes with this error in the log

```
2020-12-29T09:03:22.127022+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at initializeClass (/app/node_modules/@dguttman/wolfram-alpha-api/lib/WolframAlphaAPI.js:336:10)
2020-12-29T09:03:22.127022+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/main.js:9:15)
2020-12-29T09:03:22.127022+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
2020-12-29T09:03:22.127023+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
2020-12-29T09:03:22.127023+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
2020-12-29T09:03:22.127023+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
2020-12-29T09:03:22.127024+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
2020-12-29T09:03:22.127024+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2020-12-29T09:03:22.175669+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-29T09:03:22.207754+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Not sure what the error means or how to fix it. When I run it from my terminal the code works without any errors.

thanks in advance

Comment: The stacktrace you provided is cut off. If you can, please edit your question and include the entire stacktrace. The start of a stacktrace usually begins with `SomethingError: <message>`.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your environment variables. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713758/heroku-node-js-app-process-exited-with-status-1-and-error-h10) could help you further